# Select only characters in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have strings in a database like this:

firstname.lastname@email.com

And I only need the characters that appear after the @ symbol and before (.) symbol i.e. (email) from the above example

I am trying to find a simple way to do this in SQL.

Comment: look at CHARINDEX() and SUBSTRING()

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20984617/how-to-get-string-between-two-characters

Comment: A similar Q&A can be found [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40425080/7812927).
<br> Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do this:

```
use [your_db_name];
go

create table dbo.test
(
    string varchar(max) null
)
insert into dbo.test values ('firstname.lastname@email.com')

select 
    string,
    substring(
        string, 
        charindex('@', string, 0) + 1, 
        charindex('.', string,  charindex('@', string, 0)) - charindex('@', string, 0) - 1
    ) as you_need
from dbo.test
```

Answer (score 1):

String manipulations are such a pain in SQL Server.  Here is one method:

```
select t.*,
       left(en.emailname, charindex('.', en.emailname + '.') - 1)
from t outer apply
     (select stuff(email, 1, charindex('@', email + '@'), '') as emailname) en;
```

That that in the `charindex()` calls, the character being searched for is placed at the end of the string.  This allows the code to work even for malformed emails -- it returns an empty string when the email is not of the form `'%@%.%'`.

Answer (score 1):

```
DECLARE @str varchar(50) = 'firstname.lastname@email.com';
SELECT LEFT(
         RIGHT(@str, LEN(@str) - CHARINDEX('@', @str))
         ,CHARINDEX('.', RIGHT(@str, LEN(@str) - CHARINDEX('@', @str))
       ) - 1) AS OUTPUT
```

Above query gives only domain-name from Email. The query can be applied for column in a table

Answer (score 1):

DECLARE @col char(200) 
set @col = 'firstname.lastname@email.com'

SELECT SUBSTRING(@col, LEN(LEFT(@col, CHARINDEX ('@', @col))) + 1, LEN(@col) - LEN(LEFT(@col, CHARINDEX ('@', @col))) - LEN(RIGHT(@col, LEN(@col) - CHARINDEX ('.', @col))) - 4);

Answer (score 1):

Try This:-

```
DECLARE @Text varchar(100)
SET @Text = 'firstname.lastname@email.com'
SELECT SUBSTRING(STUFF(@Text, 1, CHARINDEX('@',@Text), ''), 0, 
CHARINDEX('.', STUFF(@Text, 1, CHARINDEX('@',@Text), '')))
```

Result:-

`email`

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @myStr varchar(100) = 'firstname.lastname@email.com'

SELECT 
SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING(@myStr,CHARINDEX('@',@myStr)+1,LEN(@myStr)-CHARINDEX('@',@myStr)+1),0,CHARINDEX('.',SUBSTRING(@myStr,CHARINDEX('@',@myStr)+1,LEN(@myStr)-CHARINDEX('@',@myStr)+1)))
```

That can be useful but I really recommend you to build user defined function in C#/Visaul basic they could be much more faster that this.

Answer (score 0):

Using charindex, len and reverse to search for the positions of the `@` and the last dot.
And substring to get the name based on those positions:

```
create table test (id int identity(1,1), email varchar(60));

insert into test (email) values 
('jane.doe@email.com'),
('not an email'),
('@invalid.email.xxx'),
('john.doe@longer.domainname.net');

select *, 
 (case 
  when email like '[a-z]%@%.%' 
  then substring(email, 
          charindex('@',email)+1,
          len(email) - charindex('@',email) - charindex('.',reverse(email))
               )
  end) as email_domain_without_extension 
from test;
```

The CASE WHEN is used to return NULL when it's not an email (instead of an empty string).